# Can anyone please assist me in hadoop/spark configuration?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to hadoop and spark (I'm using pyspark jupyter), I configured my environment and set the environment variables, however when I execute codes it always shows error messages:

> ERROR datanode.DataNode: BlockSender.sendChunks() exception:
> java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

and when I try to save my data from pyspark to hdfs or to local it keeps executing forever. And also in resource manager it shows an unhealthy node. And anyone please help me in this. Thanks

Here is my **core-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Here's my **hdfs-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:///C:/hadoop/data/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:///C:/hadoop/data/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
  <value>localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Here's my **yarn-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
<property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
 
 <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
 
 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage</name>
  <value>98.5</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

in **hadoop-env.cmd**: I set the JAVA_HOME:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk-1.8
```

And here are my environment variables:
**User variables**:

- *JAVA_HOME*: C:\Java\jdk-1.8
- *HADOOP_HOME*: C:\hadoop
- *SPARK_HOME*: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pyspark

and in the path I added `C:\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7` and `C:\Java\jdk-1.8` and `C:\hadoop`

In the **system variables**:

- *HADOOP_HOME*: C:\hadoop\bin
- *SPARK_HOME*: C:\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin

and in the path I added all the `bin` of hadoop and java and spark and also `sbin` of hadoop.

Comment: You don't need to do any of this. Create a new python environment. Install pyspark in it and that's it. You should be able to run any pyspark script. First try whether it is working in vanilla format. i.e. simple `python script.py` then you can point your jupyter notebook to that python environment.

Comment: @user238607 I also need to use hadoop since my data is stored in hdfs, that's why I had to do some configuration, but it seems that's something is wrong because everytime I run a code it shows `ERROR datanode.DataNode: BlockSender.sendChunks() exception: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`